# Able to clone but not able to push

Tags: git, github, credential-manager, git-credential-manager

I am unable to push the repository. I am able to clone the repository. I have seen in my credential manager, but I can't see my credentials saved there. I did try using

```
git config --global user.name "UserName"
git config --global user.email "Email"
```

after this I am able to only clone but not Push the changes. There is no error output from the Push as the process doesn't end. It's not even asking for my credentials to login in the account.

I also have tried uninstalling Git and reinstalling but it doesn't work. After reinstallation it has not asked me to login my github (i.e. not asked my credentials)

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how the repository is configured..
some projects are set allowing developers to clone but integrating changes can be done only over pull requests...

this is a tipical best practice to protect the master /development branch

contact the project administrator and if so, create a new branch, integrate the changes there, push it to the repo and create a pull request

Comment: I am not able to push even if I own the repository